# Mailchimp not rendering variables

Tags: c#, mailchimp, mandrill

I am using the Mailchimp template to send emails through Mandrill. Email being sent successfully. But the variables are not rendering. I tried lots of settings but unfortunately, it is not working. My code is looking like the following.

```
<p>Dear {{customerName}},</p>

<p>Thank you for using XXXXX to process your return.</p>

<p>All you have to do is bring your parcel along with&nbsp;this e-mail to {{pudoLocation}} at {{emailPudoAddress}}.</p>
```

And In the Email output, it is showing like this.

[image: EmailOutput]

And My request JSON to API **https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json** is:-

```
valid json is `{
"key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"template_name": "TestTemplate",
"template_content": [],
"message": {
    "subject": "TestEmail",
    "from_email": "xxx.xx@xxxxx.in",
    "from_name": "Drop2Shop",
    "to": [{
        "Email": "xxxxx.xxx@xxxxxx.in",
        "Name": "Amrit Pannu",
        "Type": "to"
    }],
    "headers": {
        "Reply-To": "xxxxx.xxx@xxxx.in"
    },
    "important": false,
    "track_clicks": true,
    "track_opens": true,
    "merge_language": "handlebars",
    "global_merge_vars": [{
        "name": "pudoLocation",
        "content": "TRK00000028"
    },
    {
        "name": "customerName",
        "content": "TRK00000028"
    }],
    "tags": [""]
}
```

}`

Please can someone help me here what I missing in this?
Thanks and Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can pass global variables in mandrill using `*|VAR1|*`. To pass array you can use `{{handlebars}}`.
The content will be like this:

```
<p>Dear *|customerName|*,</p>

<p>Thank you for using XXXXX to process your return.</p>

<p>All you have to do is bring your parcel along with&nbsp;this e-mail to *|pudoLocation|* at *|emailPudoAddress|*.</p>
```

The JSON should be like this only:

```
{
   "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "template_name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "template_content": [],
   "message": {
      "subject": "TestEmail",
      "from_email": "xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.in",
      "from_name": "xxxxxx",
      "to": [
         {
            "email": "xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.in",
            "name": "xxxxx xxxxx",
            "type": "to"
         }
      ],
      "headers": {
         "reply_to": "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.in"
      },
      "important": false,
      "track_opens": true,
      "track_clicks": true,
      "merge_language": "handlebars",
      "global_merge_vars": [
         {
            "name": "trackingNumber",
            "content": "TRK00000028"
         },
         {
            "name": "customerName",
            "content": "Amrit Pannu"
         },
         {
            "name": "eCommerceRetailer",
            "content": "Jojo Retailer"
         },
         {
            "name": "goodsDescription",
            "content": "Tricycles, Scooters, and Similar Wheeled Toys; Dolls' Carriages"
         },
         {
            "name": "shippingDate",
            "content": "2021-07-07"
         },
         {
            "name": "numberOfPackages",
            "content": "45"
         },
         {
            "name": "shipFromAddress",
            "content": "IRELAND"
         },
         {
            "name": "shipToAddress",
            "content": "Britain"
         },
         {
            "Name": "pudoAddress",
            "Content": "USA"
         },
         {
            "name": "shipFromContact",
            "content": "Commin"
         },
         {
            "name": "shipToContact",
            "content": "Stark"
         },
         {
            "name": "customerReference",
            "content": "DF7889FSDHCB"
         },
         {
            "name": "pudoLocation",
            "content": "Denmark"
         },
         {
            "name": "emailPudoAddress",
            "content": "amrit@mailinator.com"
         },
         {
            "name": "unsubscribePageUrl",
            "content": ""
         },
         {
            "name": "email",
            "content": "amrit@mailinator.com"
         },
         {
            "name": "scanEventTime",
            "content": "12:07"
         },
         {
            "name": "scanEventDate",
            "content": "07 July 2021"
         },
         {
            "name": "packageItems",
            "content": [
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "869c6f67-f33d-4b30-a274-79b635d12461",
                  "ReturnReason": "c3b4b071-7664-4060-a39f-52c24147a1ce",
                  "Quantity": 3,
                  "Value": 6
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "5e2c625b-74e6-4e90-bb52-6595e9f3d088",
                  "ReturnReason": "f0949b28-f9a7-406e-8676-b8ce6c714509",
                  "Quantity": 3,
                  "Value": 14
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "cffe036a-2441-41af-82e1-130f9169924b",
                  "ReturnReason": "f31956b9-c24e-492e-b11f-4b4e19489b13",
                  "Quantity": 1,
                  "Value": 5
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "f8f64467-6926-4f08-9d4e-aa924dc1af35",
                  "ReturnReason": "d1f759b0-8e54-4119-94ee-6afe1bc49766",
                  "Quantity": 4,
                  "Value": 0
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "496f4e0e-739d-4fce-8a37-85113f27c4d4",
                  "ReturnReason": "b8d98439-928f-4e6c-bb56-01e6f8fb6be6",
                  "Quantity": 2,
                  "Value": 5
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "afe2986c-e51e-4cfe-9506-f9ef2afa5657",
                  "ReturnReason": "4e6e34f6-d921-46fb-8f4a-b04afd0856a7",
                  "Quantity": 4,
                  "Value": 12
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "13ac561a-d161-46a5-9795-8481e99a3afd",
                  "ReturnReason": "73f4441b-dcff-4f68-a58e-320a29a167c8",
                  "Quantity": 1,
                  "Value": 7
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "135e083b-0408-4445-9a0c-3656a46f7eab",
                  "ReturnReason": "325c7144-8f7d-4712-b708-1702416ca02c",
                  "Quantity": 2,
                  "Value": 13
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "ee510bfd-58ea-4707-9c52-26913b190b27",
                  "ReturnReason": "854629a5-289b-46c9-a072-099e2a572307",
                  "Quantity": 4,
                  "Value": 12
               },
               {
                  "GoodsDescription": "b6d6fa6e-a327-4014-b019-0c4cd0098da6",
                  "ReturnReason": "02394799-761c-46f0-af79-d8bc92b2c1b5",
                  "Quantity": 1,
                  "Value": 13
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name": "currentYear",
            "content": 2021
         }
      ],
      "tags": null,
      "inline_css": true
   }
```

For more information, please see this: https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/templates-dynamic-content/#dynamic-content

Comment: @Harve Patel, I need to use curly braces variables only. because I also need to render an Array here and global variables accept only string values.  With the curly braces, it was working fine before. But some sort of settings are broken and it stopped working.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check that. Can you please add `"merge": true,` to your JSON request after `"merge_language": "handlebars",`.

Comment: Hello @AmritPannu, I edited the above answer.  The json format is also not correct. Can you please check that?

Comment: Hello @harve Patel, Actually sorry for that. the given JSON is wrong because I generated it from c# class.  But I am passing the correct request JSON as GlobalMergeVars is global_merge_vars in actuality. I have mentioned the JSON property name to give the proper name. Yes, It is right that the given JSON in question is wrong but in my request the JSON is proper.  I added updated json also

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably too late, but if it can help someone else.
It's not working because you have to remove all the backslashes Mailchimp added when send it to Mandrill before your variables. Change : `\{{customerName}}` to `{{customerName}}`